# Problems with bash special parameters

Tags: bash

Can someone explain why this output splits to a new line?

```sh
$ cat ./test-args.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    printf '%b %b %b %b\n' "$0" "$1" "$#" "$@"
    shift
done

$ ./test-args.sh a b c d e
./test-args.sh a 5 a
b c d e
./test-args.sh b 4 b
c d e
./test-args.sh c 3 c
d e
./test-args.sh d 2 d
e
./test-args.sh e 1 e
```

Assigning the special parameters to variables works as expected:

```sh
$ cat ./test-args.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    a=$0
    b=$1
    c=$#
    d=$@
    printf '%b %b %b %b\n' "$a" "$b" "$c" "$d"
    shift
done

$ ./test-args.sh a b c d e
./test-args.sh a 5 a b c d e
./test-args.sh b 4 b c d e
./test-args.sh c 3 c d e
./test-args.sh d 2 d e
./test-args.sh e 1 e
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `printf` receives extra arguments it repeats the format string on the extra words. For instance:

```
$ printf '[%s]\n' a b c
[a]
[b]
[c]
```

Your `printf` format string expects four arguments, but `"$@"` expands to multiple words. It's running over the format string twice which is why the `\n` shows up "in the middle". If you change your format string to `'<%b %b %b %b>\n'` it becomes clear:

```
$ ./test-args.sh a b c d e
<./test-args.sh a 5 a>
<b c d e>
<./test-args.sh b 4 b>
<c d e >
<./test-args.sh c 3 c>
<d e  >
<./test-args.sh d 2 d>
<e   >
<./test-args.sh e 1 e>
```

You can fix it by changing `"$@"` to `"$*"` so that all the arguments are passed as a single string.

And why did assigning to variables change the behavior? It's because `d=$@` doesn't preserve the "arrayness" of `$@`. Like `$*`, it concatenates the arguments into a single string. To get array behavior you'd write:

```
a=$0
b=$1
c=$#
d=("$@")
printf '%b %b %b %b\n' "$a" "$b" "$c" "${d[@]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

When `printf` is provided more attributes than its format uses, it will re-use its format. In your case `"$@"` is expanded to all parameters enclosed in double-quotes, (`"a" "b" "c" "d" "e"` in your first case) and `printf` receives 8 arguments which it displays using two occurences of its format string, giving your unexpected output.

To avoid this behaviour, you will want to use `"$*"` which will be expanded to a single argument, `"a b c d e"` in your first case.

Answer (score 0):

The think is, printf loops through the arguments. So in the first loop

```
printf '%b %b %b %b\n' "$0" "$1" "$#" "$@"
```

is expanded to

```
printf '%b %b %b %b\n' ./test-args.sh a 5 a b c d e
```

printf takes first 4 arguments `./test-args.sh a 5 a` and uses `%b %b %b %b\n` to print them. Then it takes another 4 (or less) arguments `b c d e` and uses `%b %b %b %b\n` again to print them. Basically `printf '%b %b %b %b\n' ./test-args.sh a 5 a b c d e` is the same as

```
printf '%b %b %b %b\n' ./test-args.sh a 5 a b
printf '%b %b %b %b\n' b c d e
```

So it prints multiple lines.
This will do what you want:

```
while (($#)); do
    printf '%s ' "$0" "$1" "$#" "$@"
    printf '\n'
    shift
done
```

or maybe:

```
while (($#)); do
    printf '%s %s %s %s\n' "$0" "$1" "$#" "$*"
    shift
done
```